# sed and tac: write error: Invalid argument

Tags: windows, sed, gnu, tac

I'm using GNU Coreutils on Windows. I want to get last error line from log file

The SED regex works fine (but finds first entry in file)

```
c:\path\sed -n "/70\-Error/{p;q}" MyFile.log
```

the TAC command

```
c:\path\tac MyFile.log
```

successfully reverses the whole file, without error

but when I combine the two I get the last match line from the file output, as expected, but also an error:

```
c:\path\tac MyFile.log | c:\path\sed -n "/70\-Error/{p;q}"
```

gives

```
14/02/2018 10:19:03 [9] 70-Error: Errorcode: Query returned error 524 (Query timeout)
c:\path\tac: write error: Invalid argument
```

EDIT:

```
sed -n "p" MyFile.log
```

gives output

```
sed -n "p" MyFile.log | cat
```

also gives output, with no error

```
sed -n "p" MyFile.log | sed -n "/70\-Error/{p;q}"
```

gives first matching line and error:

```
30/01/2018 10:30:28 [7] 70-Error: Action failed ....
sed: couldn't write 225 items to stdout: Broken pipe
```

Using CAT isntead of TAC:

```
cat MyFile.log | sed -n "/70\-Error/{p;q}"
```

gives first matching line then error - looks same as TAC scenario:

```
30/01/2018 10:30:28 [7] 70-Error: Action failed ...
cat: write error: Invalid argument
```

Other tests:

```
sed -n "/fe80::a828:2146:58d1:28df/{p}" MyFile.log
```

is fine but

```
sed -n "/fe80::a828:2146:58d1:28df/{p}" MyFile.log | tac
```

gives no output and only this error instead:

```
sed: couldn't flush stdout: Invalid argument
```

I thought the problem might be associated with the fact that MyFile.log had a full path, including spaces, and as such was quoted - so I copied MyFile.log to same folder as GNU tools so everything was in current folder and no complex filename ... but same thing.

```
sed -n "p" MyFile.log | tac
```

gives (first) 25 lines from file, in reverse order, then:

```
sed: couldn't write 225 items to stdout: Broken pipe
```

maybe some sort of memory / cache-size limitation?

```
sed --unbuffered
```

didn't change anything.

MyFile.log is 4MB and 27,000 lines

**EDIT2:**

```
tac MyFile.log | sed "/70\-Error/h;$!d;x"
```

works fine, even for quoted MyFile.log containing spaces

Comment: I don't use windows, here's a shot in the dark - is the error specific to tac or something else? ignoring correctness, do you get the error if you use `cat` or `sed -n 'p'` instead of `tac`?

Comment: @Sundeep thanks, good idea. I tried various combinations, results added to O/P. Appears to be some sort of general issue, presumably windows-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/70\\-Error/h;$!d;x' file
```

This copies an error message into the hold space and at the end of file prints it.

N.B. Uses `\\` to represent `\` as a single backslash is a quoting metacharacter in sed.

To print all the lines following the last error message use:

```
sed '/70-Error/h;//!H;$!d;x' file
```

To print a selective number of lines following the last error message, say 3, use:

```
sed '/70-Error/h;//!H;$!d;x;s/\(\(\n[^\n]*\)\{3\}\).*/\1/' file
```

Or, more easy on the eye:

```
sed -r '/70-Error/h;//!H;$!d;x;s/((\n[^\n]*){3}).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: Thanks.  the SED command works, but combined with TAX and PIPE gives "tac: write error: Invalid argument" (The pattern I'm looking for is "70-Error" so my "\-" was to escape the hyphen)

Comment: My mistake, I had an error in the command, its now working fine, thanks

Comment: @Kristen there is no need for tac or to pipe it to sed as it is standalone i.e. it does what you want. Also there is no need to quote a `-` so just remove the `\\`'s.

Comment: Thanks ... figured that out when I got the first line instead of the last! I'll need to get educated on the commands as what I actually need (multiple lines from end of file) isn't quite as simple as this example ... what I could really do with is: a) save the last line from the file, b) next time RegEx for ERRORS after the line that matches last-run. If you can help with that it would be much appreciated

Comment: @Kristen if you want the lines following the last error message, add the lines that do not meet the regexp to the hold space and then print those at the end of the file see edit.